# CSS rotate table but keep cell orientation

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I have an angled footer:

```css
.angled{
background-color: red;
height: 120px;
width: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 40%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 40%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="angled"></div>
```

I now want to position a navigation in it.

My thought was to use a table to structure the footer. But in order to have the items of the navigation fit inside the footer I have to rotate the table. But how can I keep the cells oriented upright, while the table is rotatet?

Or does someone have a better idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider skewing the container then unskew the element inside:

```css
.angled {
  background-color: red;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 40%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 40%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: skewY(-6deg);
}

.container>span {
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: skewY(6deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="angled">
  <div class="container">
    <span>item1</span>
    <span>item2</span>
    <span>item3</span>
    <span>item4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the angle need to change depending on the size because it defined by `tan(angle) = h/w` where `w` is the width of the element which is a block element (this is dynamic) and `h` is 40% of the height, the part removed by the `clip-path` (this one is static).

Here is a small JS code that you can add to rectify the skew angle on screen resize:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.angled');

var w = elem.offsetWidth;
elem.style.setProperty("--a", (Math.atan(48/w)*180/Math.PI )+"deg");

window.onresize = function(event) {
    w = elem.offsetWidth;
    elem.style.setProperty("--a", (Math.atan(48/w)*180/Math.PI )+"deg");
};
```

```css
.angled {
  background-color: red;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 40%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 40%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: skewY(calc(-1 * var(--a)));
}

.container>span {
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: skewY(var(--a));
}
```

```html
<div class="angled">
  <div class="container">
    <span>item1</span>
    <span>item2</span>
    <span>item3</span>
    <span>item4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And since we are using skew, you can get rid of the `clip-path` and consider the background on the skewed element:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.angled');

var w = elem.offsetWidth;
elem.style.setProperty("--a", (Math.atan(48/w)*180/Math.PI )+"deg");

window.onresize = function(event) {
    w = elem.offsetWidth;
    elem.style.setProperty("--a", (Math.atan(48/w)*180/Math.PI )+"deg");
};
```

```css
.angled {
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  color: #fff;
  background:red;
  height:100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: skewY(calc(-1 * var(--a)));
}

.container>span {
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: skewY(var(--a));
}
```

```html
<div class="angled">
  <div class="container">
    <span>item1</span>
    <span>item2</span>
    <span>item3</span>
    <span>item4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```